# Consultation about bulk insert in sql-server

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have C# WinForm program that i need to insert  sql-server.

The file is Text (Tab delimited).

Sometimes it contains (3 columns):

```
BAR    DES     MAK
111    aaa     222
333    bbb     333
.
.
```

and sometimes it contains (5 columns):

```
BAR    DES     MAK    PRI    MLA
111    aaa     222    1.1    2.2
333    bbb     333    3.3    4.4
.
.
```

The sql-server table is CatTbl:

```
BAR nvarchar(250)
DES nvarchar(250)
MAK nvarchar(250)
PRI nvarchar(250)
MLA nvarchar(250)
```

i try to insert like this:

```
SQL = @"BULK INSERT CatTbl FROM 'd:\TEST\TEST.txt' WITH (CODEPAGE=1255,FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t')";
Cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, Conn);
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Cmd.Dispose();
```

If there 5 columns it works excellent **but** if there 3 columns it crashes

I searched and found no solution. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Duplicate of msdn [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/735e2b7a-1fc2-4644-a99d-f0ffee349012/consultation-about-bulk-insert-in-sqlserver?forum=transactsql). Posting the same question independently to multiple forums is just wasting effort and karma.

Comment: a maybe useless side note: Please keep in mind that BulkInsert will force your ForeignKeys (if there are any) to be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

BULK INSERT is not very flexible. A solution would be to load the columns into a table with only one varchar column and then do your splitting/parsing later on.

Answer (score 0):

If the table doesn't match the file, create a view on the table that does, and insert into the view

```
-- Run this once in SSMS to create the view
CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT BAR,DES,MAK FROM CatTbl;

-- If your file has three columns, use this
BULK INSERT MyView FROM 'd:\TEST\TEST.txt' WITH (CODEPAGE=1255,FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t')

-- If your file has five columns, use this
BULK INSERT CatTbl FROM 'd:\TEST\TEST.txt' WITH (CODEPAGE=1255,FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t')
```